# Overriding antd variables with less on V5

Tags: reactjs, less, antd, vite, css-in-js

I'm upgrading to antd v5 and i had some issues with keeping the variables overrides made from less files with v4

i have multiple less files inside `src/theme` one of them is with the following

```
@import 'antd/lib/style/themes/variable.less';

/* font */
@font: ~'var(--font)';

/* auxiliary colors */
@secondary-color: ~'var(--secondary-color)';
@secondary-color-light: ~'var(--secondary-color-light)';
@primary-color-dark: @primary-7;
@primary-color-light: @primary-5;
@background-color: #f8f8f8;
@shadow-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
@text-color: #656565;
@secondary-text-color: #9d9d9d;
@light-text-color: #bababa;

@secondary-color-bg: @green-1;
@warning-color-bg: @orange-1;
@error-color-bg: @red-1;
@info-color-bg: @blue-1;

/* sizes */
@design-scale: 60 / 70;
@app-bar-height: 60px;

@page-padding: 40px 4vw;
@page-padding-mobile: 30px 15px;

@border-radius-base: 4px;
@border-width-base: 2px;
```

Also tried to inject `primaryColor` from  `ConfigProvider` as follows
`ConfigProvider.config({ theme: {primaryColor: '#fa259e'} });`

in `vite.config` i added the following

```
...
import { theme } from 'antd/lib';
...

const { defaultAlgorithm, defaultSeed } = theme;

const mapToken = defaultAlgorithm(defaultSeed);
const v4Token = convertLegacyToken(mapToken);

export default () => {
    return defineConfig({
       ...
       css: {
            preprocessorOptions: {
                less: {
                    javascriptEnabled: true,
                    modifyVars: v4Token,
                },
            },
        },
       ...
```

My stylings has multiple issues with spacing paddings ... also primary-color not applying

**EDIT**
I have imported `antd/dist/reset.css` and also added `v4Token` in vite config just like the documentation suggested as follows

```
...
import { convertLegacyToken } from '@ant-design/compatible/lib';
import { theme } from 'antd/lib';
...

const { defaultAlgorithm, defaultSeed } = theme;

const mapToken = defaultAlgorithm(defaultSeed);
const v4Token = convertLegacyToken(mapToken);

export default () => {
    return defineConfig({
        ...
        css: {
            preprocessorOptions: {
                less: { javascriptEnabled: true, modifyVars: v4Token },
                modifyVars: v4Token,
            },
        },
        ...
    });
};
```

the problem i have a dynamic `@primary-color` and used to use `ConfigProvider.config({ theme: defaultTheme });`

so i tried to override as bellow

```
...
<ConfigProvider
            theme={{
                token: {
                    colorPrimary: defaultTheme.primaryColor,
                },
            }}
            locale={antDesignLocal}
            direction={dir}
        >
            {children}
        </ConfigProvider>
...
```

It changes the color successfully, but the components or elements using less files `@primary-color` is still set by the default blue color of antd

Comment: How did you tackle this problem in the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think your problem is that antd v5 does not support LESS anymore

[image]

See here https://ant.design/docs/react/migration-v5

Unfortunately I do not have an easy solution for you, other than sticking to v4 as long as you need LESS support.

Comment: I know about them dropping LESS, but i'm thinking of a migration shortcut. rather then re-typing everything in CSS-in-JS

Comment: Not sure if it would work, but what if you simply build your styles outside of antd, e.g. directly with the LESS compiler and then include that compiled stylesheet in your app?

Comment: I'm not seeing a migration shortcut as the two approaches (e.g. LESS vs cssinjs) are very different in nature. There is a v5 codemod tool, but I have my doubts that it would be solving your problem, if you haven't yet check it out regardless https://github.com/ant-design/codemod-v5

Comment: tried the codemod but it skipp all the less files

Comment: Can you check the changes ?

Answer (score 1):

I rewrited defaultSeed tokens and it works good for me.

```js
const withLess = require('next-with-less');
const { theme } = require('antd/lib');
const { convertLegacyToken } = require('@ant-design/compatible/lib');

const { defaultAlgorithm, defaultSeed } = theme;

const mapToken = defaultAlgorithm({
    ...defaultSeed,
    colorPrimary: '#115dee',
});

const v4Token = convertLegacyToken(mapToken);

module.exports = withLess({
    lessLoaderOptions: {
        lessOptions: {
            modifyVars: v4Token,
            javascriptEnabled: true,
        },
    },
});
```

Comment: Can you explain what happens here? Where do we load the less variables and how does it get converted to a v5 compatible theme?

Comment: Tried this one but it is not working. Can you please help me with mine?

Comment: it's in next.js configuration file, you need to use 'next-with-less'